# How to display "You Save XXX" in product lisitng page in magento Go?

Tags: magento, magento-go

I need to add "you save $xxx " amount in product listing page.

how could i add this in product listing page only and that in magento go?

is that possible to do that?

Please anyone suggest me..

Thanks

Comment: this is in magento go. so i have no access to any phtml files. i have created attribute for "you save " and value.and set in product listing display yes. but doesn't display that attribute

Comment: I think you should ask support to Magento Go team ...

Answer (score 2):

In order to display a "You Save" for "Special Price" products in magento--to make it look similar to amazon's price display--you can do the following:

**Copy**

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml
```

**to**

```
app/design/frontend/default/YOURTEMPLATE/template/catalog/product/price.phtml
```

Then in price.phtml that you just copied, right above:

Below this code:

```
<?php endif; /* if ($_finalPrice == $_price): */ ?>
```

**Insert**

```
<?php // KZN Show discounted percentage and price ?>
    <?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
    <?php 
    $_savePercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price) * 100); 
    $_saveAmount = number_format(($_price - $_finalPrice), 2);  
    ?>
        <p class="yousave">
            <span class="price-label label">You Save: </span>
            <span class="price">
                <strong class="save-amount">$<?php echo $_saveAmount; ?></strong> (<?php echo $_savePercent; ?>%)
            </span>
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php // KZN Show discounted percentage and price ?>
```

**Then you'll probably want to style it. So insert this into your theme stylesheet (e.g. style.css)**

```
/********** < Product Prices */
.price { white-space:nowrap !important; }

.price-label { font:normal 12px/15px verdena, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; white-space:nowrap; display:inline-block; width:80px; text-align:right; color:#666; }

.price-box { margin:5px 0 10px; }
.price-box .price { font-size:13px; line-height:22px;font-weight:bold; color:#3399ff; }

/* Regular price */
.regular-price { color:#3399ff; }
.regular-price .price { font-size:18px; font-weight:normal; color:#900; font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}
.product-view .regular-price .price {}
.product-view .regular-price .price:before { content:"Price: "; color:#666; font:normal 12px/15px verdena, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* Old price */
.old-price { margin:0; }
.old-price .price-label { }
.old-price .price {  font-weight:normal; font-size:13px; color:#000; text-decoration:line-through; }

/* Special price */
.special-price { margin:0; }
.special-price .price-label { }
.special-price .price { font-size:18px; font-weight:normal; color:#900; font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}


/* You save price */
.yousave { margin:0; }
.yousave .price-label { }
.yousave .price { font-weight:normal; color:#900; font-family:verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}
```

Of course you may need to adjust the CSS classes to reflect your theme. But now you'll have something that resembles Amazon's price display.

**Reference**

http://duntuk.com/add-you-save-amount-and-percentage-special-price-magento